# Attempting to email a user with custom inputs through JS

Tags: javascript, html, email

I'm trying to use [smtpjs.com](https://smtpjs.com) as a way to email my company. This is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```js
Email.send({
    Host : "gmail.com",
    Username : "####",
    Password : "####",
    To : 'test@gmail.com',
    From : "testemail@gmail.com",
    Subject : "Hello world!",
    Body : "Body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
```

I would like the code to take the three inputs that are given in the HTML and put what was given into the email and send it to wherever it needs to go. How should I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a certain input using the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and selecting the id of the input then getting its value. for instance that would be the value of the first name input in your HTML code:

```js
const firstName = document.querySelector('#fname').value;
```

in order to get the right value when the user will hit the send button, you'll need to do it when the `click` event of the send button would be triggered, but I'm guessing that that's where the `Email.send` method is.

you can get the element with the [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method too.